# Пошук незамуленого словника спортових термінів

Tags: resource-request, словники, альтернативні-правописи

Здрастуйте! Шукаю, як то кажуть, *незамулений* український словник спортової термінології: аби вийшов друком до тридцятих чи був виданий діяспорою; щось на цей кшталт. Буду дуже вдячний, якщо допоможете відшукати такий.

Comment: Будь ласка, завжди пояснюйте терміни, що ви використовуєте. Що значить «незамулений»? Вільний від іноземних слів? Будь-якого походження? Ті, що походженням зі староболгарської чи старословʼянської, вважаються іноземними? А з англійської («ногомʼяч», «рукомʼяч», «базамʼяч»)? А з японської («голіруч»)?

Comment: @bytebuster, так автор написав же: «аби вийшов друком до тридцятих чи був виданий діяспорою».

Comment: @Sasha, от мені якраз і здалося, що слово «незамулений» не дуже корелює з роком видання або видавцем. Сподіваюся, автор виправить цей недолік до того, як набереться голосів для закриття запитання як Needs details or clarity.

Comment: @bytebuster, я так розумію, під замуленістю автор має на увазі перш за все потрапляння під радянський вплив. (Я особисто не вважаю радянський вплив чимось безперечно поганим, але думка про те, що радянський влив — це саме те, чого слід у першу чергу позбуватися, дуже поширена, тому я не розумію, чому Ви настільки звернули увагу на це слово. От R2U прямо в заголовку пише: «З незамулених джерел».)

Comment: Я голосую за закриття цього питання через відсутність в ньому деталей.

Answer (score 2):

На [сторінці іншого запитання](/q/3066) в контексті обговорення незапозичених спортивних термінів згадуються такі словники:

- [«Словник чужомовних слів і термінів»](https://archive.org/stream/shtepa1977), Павло Штепа (1977, Монреаль).
- «Словник спортивної лексики», укладачі Осінчук і Левків (2002, Львів).

Ще багато словників представлені на [E2U](https://e2u.org.ua) й [R2U](https://r2u.org.ua) (частина з них видані в дорадянські часи).